# getting data from list of promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

`yourCarts` variable is list of `id(string)`,  `yourCarts = [id1, id2, id3, .....];`
I want to iterate over `yourCarts` list, for each id fetch a doc from firestore and ultimately wants to get a list of objects, and then update the state of component but i am unable to get the list of objects instead getting a list of promise.

```js
{
  getYourCartList();

  async function getYourCartList() {
    const userRefID = localStorage.getItem("uid");

    try {
      const userDoc = (await getDoc(doc(db, "clients", userRefID))).data();
      const yourCarts = userDoc?.yourCarts;

      async function getCart(cartRefID) {
        try {
          const snapShot = (
            await getDoc(doc(db, "products", cartRefID))
          ).data();
          return { ...snapShot, id: cartRefID };
        } catch (error) {
          //......
          return { id: cartRefID };
        }
      }

      if (yourCarts) {
        setShoppingCart(yourCarts.map((cartRefID) => getCart(cartRefID)));
      }

      console.log("cartlist : ", cartlist);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error occurs");
    }
  }
}
```

Suggest me where i am doing wrong

Comment: You never await the promises returned by `getCart`? For handling the list of promises, you'll want to use `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous functions return promises. The `async`/`await` keywords are just the syntax that hides some of this for you, making the code more readable.

As an example, these two functions are identical:

```js
async function test() {
  return `someValue`
}
```

```js
function test() {
  return new Promise((resolve, error) => {
    resolve(`someValue`);
  })
}
```

Now, as for your code. You have this line:

```js
setShoppingCart(yourCarts.map((cartRefID) => getCart(cartRefID)));
```

The function `getCart` is asynchronous. It returns a promise. To obtain the actual return value, it is necessary to resolve this promise. We can use `Promise.all` to create a new promise, which resolves when all promises given to it have been resolved. Subsequently, you can use `await` keyword to get the return value, an array containing the return values.

```js
setShoppingCart(await Promise.all(yourCarts.map((cartRefID) => getCart(cartRefID))));
```

Comment: Thank you @Bergi for the edit. Can't believe I made that error. Good to have an extra pair of eyes :-)